# How can I turn a game idea into an actual game?

Tags: world-building

I've been wanting to create a role-playing game for a long time. I've had tons of ideas but I haven't been able to turn those ideas into something real.

I've even thought of different kinds of stories and game possibilities occuring in the same universe, kinda like *World of Darkness*, but again, I don't know where to start.

I usually start by defining the different kinds of characters and the abilities they'd have, but it's always so empty...

Where should I begin? *How* should I begin?

---

*edit for making the question less broad*:

So far, I've thought of a fictional universe and a story explaining the reasons why such universe exists in the first place.

I've thought of a multiverse coexisting in the same plane, and worlds in them; how they are different from each other and how they are alike.

I've thought of different types of characters, abilities, political systems and the world where a new character will start.

I've thought of its history and the background of the different types of characters, their defining features and specialities.

But once i've defined the major plane of existance, the world and the broader things, and then the classes and stuff, I get stuck. I have all this information but i dont know how to put it together and make something out of it.

```
PS: sorry for bad grammar or language mistakes, but english is not my mother language.
```

---

*another edit:*

I mean, after I've defined those things, I'm like "okay, lets make a character sheet" but then i feel like theres no way the things i imagined can actually be placed together to make something nice or even *decent*. It ends up feeling like a bad copy of D&D or WoD.

Comment: Besides being very very broad, you might want to consider telling a bit about what you have so far: A basic idea but need a system idea how to build a system? A system skeleton but can't flesh out specific rules? Something entirely different?

Comment: This is too broad. You might want to edit it in order to get better answers

Comment: Hello dsc, and welcome to the site. Kindly take the [tour] and enjoy your stay here! While your question is fundamentally a good one, it is also too broad to fit into our Q&A format, so it has been put on hold. A good start for improving this question is to start smaller, focusing on individual problems you encounter when designing your game. Be mindful to keep your questions within the scope of our site. I hope you find the answers you're looking for here!

Comment: [Related.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/8659/8610) [And related.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/41541/8610)

Comment: I feel like the site should have answers available for a question like this, even if the answer is *There's no right answer only opinions. An artist begins making a work of art where the artist must begin.* However, I also feel like multiple answers that each offer *one and only one possible starting point* would allow a best answer to rise to the top, but I think enforcing this would be a mod nightmare. In other words, dsc, I don't think the site can help you with this: go ahead and get started and when you get stuck, come back, and the site'll try to unstick you.

Comment: To properly answer a question like this, it would first be useful to know of dsc wants to make a commercial product intended for distribution, or something used for their own circle of friends at home. To make a commercial grade product requires a totally different set of tools, like layout, artists, marketing, and copy right infringement substitutes like "MacDoodles Restaurants" and "Justice Sneakers", or "Halfings/Kender" instead of "Hobbits", not to mention keeping the content and language safe for kids. Only two things are true in both versions: A title, and a table of contents.

Comment: As I understand it, he has a World, but needs to develop a system. I think, that wuestion can be salvaged with heavy work and cutting... like making the question focussed on "When I have developed a rough outline of a world, how can I develop a system that benefits the type of stories I want to be told with it?" and then focussing on explaining what type of game is intended. On the other hand: you could pop into the chat in a bit, then ask there: we know lots of different games and systems in the collective, so we might help to either pinpoint hints for building or this question's revision.